# wso2Is with Multiple Ldap

Tags: ldap, multi-tenant, wso2-identity-server

Our  Requirement  is  to  connect  wso2Is  with  Multiple External  Ldap

where  each  Tenant  having  Separate  LdapServer  so  ,  that xacml  Policy  stored  in  wso2Is belongs   to  Particular  Tenet

Let  say  we  have  to  Domain  foo.com  and  bar.com

if  i  create  tenant  using  foo.com the  it  will  point  to  one  external  Ldap  and  if  we  created  tenant  using bar.com  if  will  point  to  other  external  Ldap

is  their  any  scenario  like  this on  wso2Is

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Support Image]

**1. Create first User store manager and give first ldap URL for connectionURL.

2. Then create second useer store manager and give second ldap URL for connectionURL.**

Here is the architecture.

[image: Architecture]

Answer (score 0):

You can use secondary user stores[1] feature for your requirement. You can configure one ldap in foo.com and other ldap in bar.com as secondary user stores.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Secondary+User+Stores
Thanks
Isura

Comment: i  had  used  secondary  user-store  as  Ldap  and  i  had  configured  2  seconaday  userstore  i  mean  2  ldap  connnection

Comment: i  need  2  ldap,  2  tenent  like  1  tenant  store  in  one  ldap  and  other  in  other  tenant  in  other   ldap .is  it  possible

Comment: Yes, you can log in to as tenant admin user and create a secondary user store, so it will contain users of that tenant and will be only visible for that tenant.